# laravel 5 route not working?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I have this link in my update file:

```
<a href="{{ url("detach/$team->id/group/$user->id") }}">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Detach from this group</button>
</a>
```

And this is the route:

```
Route::resource('groups', 'TeamsController');
Route::get('detach/{user_id}/group/{team_id}', 'TeamsController@detach_user')->name("groups.detach_user");
```

When i click on the button it should go to the detach_user but instead it goes to the update function, and this how the url look like.

```
localhost/group/1
```

I don't know what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the HTML code you've provided placed within the form tag? If that's the case, you might fire the form submit rather than a link click. That would explain your case.

So, if that's the case, just place the link code outside the form tag.

Answer (score 0):

Change the declaration order from this:

```
Route::resource('groups', 'TeamsController');
Route::get('detach/{user_id}/group/{team_id}', 'TeamsController@detach_user')->name("groups.detach_user");
```

To:

```
Route::get('detach/{user_id}/group/{team_id}', 'TeamsController@detach_user')->name("groups.detach_user");
Route::resource('groups', 'TeamsController');
```

According to the documentation, it could be a problem. [Check the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers):

> Supplementing Resource Controllers
>
> If it becomes necessary to add additional routes to a resource
>   controller beyond the default resource routes, you should define those
>   routes before your call to Route::resource; otherwise, the routes
>   defined by the resource method may unintentionally take precedence
>   over your supplemental routes